# gson model for json array without key

Tags: json, gson

I have the following json from our customer:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "delivery_date":  1234567890,

    "actions": [
        [ "foo", true],
        [ "bar", true]
    ],
    "customer":  {
        "id": 12345,
        "company": "",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "action": ["dothis", true]
    },
    "childs": [ 123abc2132312312,11232432943493]
}
```

I want to parse the "actions" array as a List< Actions> actionList and the single "action" as Action action.

With

```
class Action {
  String action;
  boolean yesno;
}
```

And the childs Array as List< Child> childs with

```
class Child{
  String id
}
```

Is that possible without the json keys?

Comment: Is the structure set? I don't see any reason behind having two element arrays in actions

Comment: You can make the `List<Child>` a parameter of `Action`. It should populate accordingly. If you want to keep them seperate, then create another class to GSON from, then split it.

Comment: yep the structure is set. I already asked to change the json to key-value pairs - without success :(

Comment: Oh and childs should be an array of ints

Comment: Thank you! But childs are alphanumeric. As you can't see - sorry :)

Comment: Are you sure? There are no quotations around the numbers. If you want to store it after as a String, you should do it after GSON. See below code, and see if it works

Comment: To do it right, I would suggest you write a deserializer registered with the respective classes Action and Child and have a parent entity holding these two. That way when parsing the whole json, gson will automatically assign the deserializer you have just written. I can provide details if you are interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it my self with a custom deserializer. Thanks to  dzsonni for the hint.

In the Gson root class:

```
private ArrayList<Action> parcel_actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
```

the action class

```
class Action {
  String action;
  boolean yesno;
}
```

the deserializer:

```
public class ActionDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<Action>> {

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Action> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ArrayList<Actions> list = new ArrayList<Action>(){};

        if(json.getAsJsonArray().get(0).isJsonPrimitive()){
            String action = json.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsString();
            boolean doIt = json.getAsJsonArray().get(1).getAsBoolean();
            list.add(new Action(action, doIt));
        }
        else {
            for(JsonElement element : json.getAsJsonArray()) {
                String action = element.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsString();
                boolean doIt = element.getAsJsonArray().get(1).getAsBoolean();
                list.add(new Action(action, doIt));
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

then just add it to your gson

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<ArrayList<Action>>(){}.getType(), new ActionsDeserializer()); 
Gson gson = builder.create();
```

Comment: Good job. Looks ideal. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Your action class is ok, i mis-read slightly.

Add a complete class:

```
class Delivery {
  Int32 id;
  Int32 delivery_date;
  list<Action> actions;
  Customer customer;
  list<Int32> childs;
}
```

actions will be parsed as a paramtere inside, as will childs.
Then you need to create a Customers class too, which is part of this. (or exclude it, and GSON will ignore it)

This will populate the `int`s into `childs` and `Actions` into `actions`.

If indeed, childs is alphanumeric, then just change it to String.

You can then access it via,

```
  Delivery delivery = GSON ... etc
  var x = delivery.actions;  // Actions
  var y = delivery.childs; // Childs
```

Comment: How ill gson automatically parse the above json into this class? Childs isnt even a part of the actions key

Comment: @dzsonni Your right, i skimmed over an important aspect. He needs to GSON the whole thing as a class.

Comment: Thank you, yep that is one possibility but I wanted a complete clean solution, so I tried it with a custom deserializer.