# Gson parse Array without key and different type

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I've got json like this

```
[123,"some text"]
```

I've parse it using something like

```
class Some {
    public Integer number;
    public String text;
}

Some some = new Some();
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray jsonArray = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
some.number = jsonArray.get(0).getAsInt();
some.text = jsonArray.get(1).getAsString();
```

I want to use gson, since all of my code using it. I'm googling and the possible solution is making custom deserializer, like in here
[gson model for json array without key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467136/gson-model-for-json-array-without-key). But it become more complex, and not readable than the code i already use.

Is there any other way using gson to parse this?

Comment: And just what is wrong with using a custom deserializer/serializer?

Comment: @fge It become more "not readable" (for me at least) than just using ordinary way (like code above)